# How show number without decimals and with a separator?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server.

What order I have to use to show this number 155844,56 as 155.844

I used `convert(int, 155844,56)` but got 155844,56
I also used `format` but it also did not work.

Comment: How does `155844,56` become `155.844`?

Comment: You got it. Better 155.845

Comment: I got what? I was asking *how* you achieve the result you want.

Comment: I don't think this statement is true:  "convert(int, 155844,56) but got 155844,56".

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

select round(155844,56,2);

Answer (score 0):

I gets you the value, but I doubt it's the logic you want:

```sql
SELECT convert(int, 155844,56) /1000.0;
```

Comment: Round up or down to this nearst int and the give me seperations as "."

Comment: Formatting is for the presentation layer, not SQL, @Mail . Numerical data types don't have "formats".

Comment: what? I do not understand what you mean

Comment: It means exactly what it says; do the formatting in the presentation, not in the the SQL. Numerical data types don't have a "format" they, like dates, are binary values with no format property. How a value in displayed in your application is up to the application. It's the application you need to change, not the SQL,

Comment: If I export the date without format, than excel does not recognise the numbers because its contain "." as decimal, but I need ",".

Comment: Then you're ETL process is wrong, even Excel respects data types, poorly. You're clearly exporting the numerical data types as a string, *not* a numerical value. That is the *real* problem... This appears to be a  great example of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0):

```
select Format(155844.56,'#,0')
```

works fine for me

[image]

Comment: Its this right: select Format(1558444.56,'##,0')

Comment: @Mail please accept the answer if you can. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why but this works

**select Format(15548444.46,'#,0')**

Its round up or down to the nearsten int. Cut the last 2 decimals and give me seperations ".".

Do someone understand why it works? Are their better alternatives?